# Grant privileges in other table than mysql table

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have been requested to create a back-end area for an existing website (on a provider's server), consisting of several tables and php pages. 
This back-end area should not be accessible/visible to our normal website vistors, so a login system (php) has been developed.
I am also expected to be able to grant privileges (select, insert etc.) for those who CAN access this back-end area. However, I have no access to the mysql db on the provider's server.
Is it possible to create and use a separate table for granting privileges on my tables or can privileges only be set in the mysql db itself ?
Any suggestions/help welcome. Thx, LBox

Comment: Build your on authentication system.  Implement it in PHP.  Don't give any "users" direct login access to mysql.  Let them get to the database only through PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

No. Grants are not defined per database (as in mongodb 2.4). mysql database is a centralized system of records for authentication etc... (just like admin database in mongodb 2.6+).

You might want to refer the document for [mysql privilege system](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privilege-system.html).